# Farseer: Shooting a ball in a certain angle?

Tags: xna, c#, physics, farseer-physics-engine

How can I shoot a ball in a certain angle? When I press the Space key, the ball should be shot in a 45 degree angle. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
float angle = MathHelper.ToRadians(45);
float power = 20; // <- tunable value

Vector2 direction = new Vector2((float)Math.Cos(angle), (float)Math.Sin(angle));

fixture.Body.ApplyLinearImpulse(power * direction);
```

The above applies an instantaneous force to the object. You could also set `Body.LinearVelocity` directly.

To check for the space key being pressed (rather than held down), you want to do something like this:

```
 KeyboardState keyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();

 if(keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space) && lastKeyboardState.IsKeyUp(Keys.Space))
 {
     // apply the impulse here
 }

 lastKeyboardState = keyboardState; // store this between frames
```

Comment: Thanx. It works.

Comment: @Bryan Please note a correction I have made to my answer - I just noticed I had `sin` and `cos` reversed! (Angles should be `x = cos` and `y = sin`.)